# Capturar texto de una cadena esplícita y no sólo un fragmento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Con la siguiente cadena en un documento html, 'este verano vamos a la playa a mi vera' necesito capturar la palabra 'vera' y estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
var text = 'vera';
var modulo = '<pre>' + text + '</pre>';
$(pagesText).html(function () {
      return $(this).html().replace(text, modulo); 
});
```

Sucede que, me añade dos tags pre, uno en el trozo de la palabra 'verano' en unos 4 primeras letras y el que únicamente quiero que es 'vera'.

Cómo capturo sólo la palabra 'vera' y no 'verano' aunque contenga esos 4 primeros caracteres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo a través de una expresión regular para que te sustituya solo y exclusivamente la palabra "vera", independientemente de donde se encuentre en el texto y del número de veces que aparezca.

```js
var text = 'vera';
var modulo = '<pre>' + text + '</pre>';
var pagesText = 'vera durante este verano a mi vera, lo único que quería era verte a mi vera.';
var expresion = new RegExp('\\b' + text + '\\b', 'g');

console.log (pagesText.replace(expresion, modulo));
```

Comment: Gracias. Puedo poner el siguiente método con el nombre de la variable entre la expresión regular?   pageText.replace(/(^|\W)text($|\W)/g, modulo);

Comment: Se podría, pero para ello habría que usar el constructor de la clase `RexExp`, asegurándote de escapar las "\" de la expresión regular. He editado la respuesta para contemplar esa posibilidad.

Comment: Ahora si me permite realizar un cambio pero, me ha eliminado el espacio de antes de 'vera' y el punto de después. Hay que cambiar la expresión en este caso?

Comment: Actualicé de nuevo la respuesta para que deje fuera del `replace` el caractér anterior y posterior al patrón de reemplazo.

Comment: Perfecto, esto es  justo lo que tiene que hacer. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo utilizando [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp):

```js
var string = 'este verano vamos a la playa a mi vera'
var text = 'vera';
var modulo = '<pre>' + text + '</pre>';

console.log(string.replace(/vera$/, modulo))
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías hacerlo de manera de `var text = 'vera '` tenga ese espacio para que no tome verano, no sé si te sirva, saludos

Comment: Es una opción pero si hay más 'vera' en un párrafo, ya no valdría por ejemplo con un punto al final u otro caracter como una coma.