# Expresión regular para reemplazar cadena de texto no lo hace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo esta función para buscar palabras separadas por espacios y que las reemplace por la misma palabra dentro de una etiqueta div. La búsqueda puede ser en varias páginas que son divs separados con la clase 'page' Esta es mi función.

```
        var pagesText = $('.pages'),
            text = 'sesgó',
            modulo = '<div>' + text + '</div>';

        if (text !== '') {
            $(pagesText).html(function () {
                var finalText = new RegExp('\\b' + text + '\\b', 'g');
                console.log(finalText);
                return $(this).html().replace(finalText, modulo); 
            });
        }
```

En este caso, hace todo lo que necesito correctamente metiendo en un div tantas palabras idénticas en todas las páginas pero, no lo hace por ejemplo con palabras que terminan en acento. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Creo que habias preguntado esto si no mal  recuerdo en otra parte, pero no puedo encontrar la pregunta...

Comment: Hace casi 1 año (me sorprendería que te acordaras si hablamos de la misma) solicité ayuda para capturar texto, información de la que está aquí es parte de la sacada allá pero, la parte del acento o caracteres especiales al final en la última letra, no la reemplaza. Este es el enlace original: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276741/capturar-texto-de-una-cadena-esplícita-y-no-sólo-un-fragmento